# Overleaf keeps complaining when math mode is defined inside \newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, overleaf

I have a perfect newcommand as follows:

```
\newcommand{\inPlaceEq}[1]{
    \scalebox{0.86}{\ensuremath{#1}}
}
```

Even though it compiles and works out perfectly, the editor(overleaf) keeps complaining about the following piece of instructions:

```
\inPlaceEq{P(\theta|\mathcal{D})}
```

Saying: "\theta must be inside math mode". It is just annoying, except that it works. How can I resolve this weird editor-related issue?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I think this might really be an editor issue, since the editor does not recognize `\inPlaceEq` as a macro setting its argument in math mode. But then I think the overleaf editor is off-topic here.

Comment: So... It is something up to developers of overleaf? I see

Comment: @campa yes realised later and had removed my comment

Comment: As your question is highly Overleaf-specific, please post it to the Overleaf Helpdesk. I here their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Yes, Overleaf questions should go to Overleaf :) By "Overleaf complaining" you probably mean the code check. The Overleaf code check may not pick up on user defined macros, but it is easy to selectively turn off to avoid spurious warnings: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Code_Check.